# How to trigger a broadcast to read an incoming text on button click event?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, text-to-speech, telephonymanager

In my app, I have two Broadcast Receivers registered with `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` I want one of them to be always running in the background(Decrypt) and one of them to be active only when a button is clicked(DrivingMode).

The DrivingMode Broadcast Receiver has a `speakSMS()` which causes it to crash. Or else the BR is triggered just fine.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Here's my LogCat:

[image]

Sorry, I couldn't save it into a .TXT file and copy paste it here :(

This is DrivingMode.java :

```
package com.example.callandmessagemanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

public class DrivingMode extends Activity {
    private static TextToSpeech myTts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.message_m);
        myTts = new TextToSpeech(this,ttsInitListener);


    }

private TextToSpeech.OnInitListener ttsInitListener=new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int version) {
            // myTts.speak(""+o, 0 ,null);

        }
    };
    public static void speakSMS(String sms)
    {
        myTts.speak(sms,0,null);

    }


}
```

Comment: paste code of DrivingMode.java with pointing line no 29.

Comment: `myTts.speak(sms,0,null);` This is the 29th line of DrivingMode.java

Comment: And I've posted the DrivingMode.java code (all of it, in the question summary)